# Python import function with package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to import a function from another python file. The problem is that I either have to call it with `file.function()` or import it with `from file import function`.

Since my file contains only one function, I am looking for a way to import it directly with `import file`.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: The only way to get around this is to write your own module loader that can build up your module namespace before it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. Why not just:

```
from file import function

function(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `from file import function` is an issue, but the only other way to do it (other than calling `file.function()` everythime) is to do `from file import *`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is with either option that you listed.

What you can do is turn your module (the file with the function you want to import) into a script by adding `if __name__ == "__main__":` to the end of your file like so:

```
# file.py
def function(...):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    function(sys.argv[1])
```

then import it as `import file`.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts

*I personally don't see an issue with alternative you listed, but the docs do have this to say about what you're trying to achieve:*

> This is often used either to provide a convenient user interface to a module, or for testing purposes (running the module as a script executes a test suite).